# regular expression to extract part of email address

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use a regular expression to extract the part of an email address between the "@" sign and the "." character. This is how I am currently doing it, but can't get the right results.

```
company = re.findall('^From:.+@(.*).',line)
```

Gives me:

```
['@iupui.edu']
```

I want to get rid of the `.edu`

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html

Comment: dot needs to be escaped in regex

Comment: Domain names often contain more than one dot, do you wish to match the first or the last dot?

Comment: I only want the domain name. so if I have abc.def@ghi.mn I want to extract ghi @Ctx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match a literal `.` in your regex, you need to use `\.`, so your code should look like this:

```
company = re.findall('^From:.+@(.*)\.',line)
#                                  ^ this position was wrong
```

See it [live here](https://regex101.com/r/gM6aI3/1).

Note that this will always match the last occurrence of `.` in your string, because `(.*)` is greedy. If you want to match the *first* occurence, you need to exclude any `.` from your capturing group:

```
company = re.findall('^From:.+@([^\.]*)\.',line)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

See a [demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/4tVEr6O4Ka0Gp9C5).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
(?<=\@)(.*?)(?=\.)
```

See a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uF9dS3/1).

Answer (score 2):

A simple example would be:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(".*(?<=\@)(.*?)(?=\.)", "From: atc@moo.com")
['moo']
>>> re.findall(".*(?<=\@)(.*?)(?=\.)", "From: atc@moo-hihihi.com")
['moo-hihihi']
```

This matches the hostname regardless of the beginning of the line, i.e. it's *greedy*.

Answer (score 1):

You could just split and find:

```
s = " abc.def@ghi.mn I"
s = s.split("@", 1)[-1]
print(s[:s.find(".")])
```

Or just split if it is not always going to match your string:

```
s = s.split("@", 1)[-1].split(".", 1)[0]
```

If it is then find will be the fastest:

```
i = s.find("@")
s = s[i+1:s.find(".", i)]
```